# How to get the input from dynamically-created EditTexts?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-edittext

I have a `Button` that adds a row with an `EditText` to a `TableLayout`. I need to find out the input in each `EditText` of the rows that are added.

For example: Someone adds 3 rows, meaning there are 3 `EditText`. In each `EditText`, they put the number 3. I need to store the values of the `EditText` that were added to the layout and add them all up by the click of a button.

Would I use a list then iterate that list? I'm not sure about how I would do this.

This is my code so far...

```
int count = 1;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSavedState();

    Button buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button buttonDel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button buttonCalc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonDel.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    TableLayout tableLayout1 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
    List<EditText> allEd = new ArrayList<EditText>();

    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            if(count != 16){
                count++;

                // Create the row only when the add button is clicked
                TableRow tempRow = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
                EditText tempText1 = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                EditText tempText2 = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                TextView tempTextView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                tempTextView.setText(count + ".");

                tempRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tempText1.setLayoutParams(editText1.getLayoutParams());
                tempText2.setLayoutParams(editText2.getLayoutParams());
                tempTextView.setLayoutParams(textView3.getLayoutParams());
                tempText1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                tempText2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
                tempText2.setId(count);
                allEd.add(tempText2);

                tempRow.addView(tempTextView);
                tempRow.addView(tempText1);
                tempRow.addView(tempText2);
                tableLayout1.addView(tempRow);
            } 
            else {
                final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create(); //Read Update
                alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                alertDialog.setMessage("You can only have 10 rows!");

                alertDialog.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            if(count != 1){
                count--;
                tableLayout1.removeView(tableLayout1.getChildAt(count));
        } 
            else {
                final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create(); //Read Update
                alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                alertDialog.setMessage("You must have at least one row!");

                alertDialog.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            String[] strings = new String[allEd.size()];
            for(int i = 0; i < allEd.size(); i++) {
                strings[i] = allEd.get(i).getText().toString();
                int input = Integer.parseInt(strings[i]);

                final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create(); //Read Update
                alertDialog.setTitle("Your calculated GPA");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Your calculated GPA is: " + input/count);
                alertDialog.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
            }
        break;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create each of the `EditText`s, you need to to add them to an array-like container, such as an `ArrayList<EditText>`. Whenever you need to access any of these dynamic `EditText`s, you can retrieve them from the `ArrayList`.

I can see that you are already creating an `ArrayList<EditText>` in your `onClick()` method. That's great, but you need to move the `ArrayList` outside the `onClick()` method so that you can reference it from any other methods you create. So move this line...

```
List<EditText> allEd = new ArrayList<EditText>();
```

outside the method, so that the beginning few lines of `onClick()` now look like this...

```
List<EditText> allEd = new ArrayList<EditText>();

public void onClick(View v) {
    TableLayout tableLayout1 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.button1:
```

Also, make sure you're adding all the `EditText`s to the `ArrayList` - I see there is a line `allEd.add(tempText2);` but I can't see any line for `allEd.add(tempText1);` - if you need to access `tempText1`, make sure you add it to the list.

To perform the 'adding' caluclation, you need to loop over the entries in the `ArrayList`, get their values, then add them together. Something like this...

```
case R.id.button3:
    // calculate the value first
    int calculation = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<allEd.size();i++){
        // get the entry
        EditText textField = addEd.get(i);

        try {
            // get the value, as a number
            int numberValue = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
            // add it to the calculation
            calculation += numberValue;
        } 
        catch (Exception e){
            // ignore errors if the input is empty or isn't a number
        }
    }

    // now display the result
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Your calculated GPA");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Your calculated GPA is: " + input/count);
    alertDialog.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
break;
```

Comment: I added a "calculate" button to my onClick method and by moving the ArrayList outside of the onClick, the calculate button was correctly able to show me each of the individual inputs. So how would I go about adding each of the inputs?

Comment: Do you mean, adding the values together? You will need to loop over all the contents of the `ArrayList`, get the value, and add them together.

Comment: Yes. I added my button3 onClick to question I posted. I want to get each referenced value, add it, then spit it back out to the user.

Comment: See my edited answer for some assistance with this. You've almost got it right, but you need to perform the calculation first, and then only show the result at the end. So, move your alertDialog out of the loop. I have just updated my answer to include your `button3` code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep references to the `EditText`s that are added with each button press. Since you don't know how many will be added, I suggest using a `List<EditText>` to store them. Make this a member variable and then you can access the input from the `EditText`s in the list.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to answer. This is a very easy way to access dinamycally added elements.